# Pandas add a row having particular data after a set of common elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in python pandas having this structure

```
A    B      C      D
cat   Jack  Tail  short
cat   Jack  Tail  Medium
cat   Jack  Tail  Long
cat   Na    eye  blue
cat   Mik  Tail  short
cat   Mik  Tail  Medium
cat   Moon  Tail  short
dog   Min   Tail  short
dog   Spoon   Tail  short
dog   Spoon   Tail  medium
dog   Spoon   Tail  Long
```

How should I do it in python pandas to obtain the mentioned new and enriched dataframe?
Now I would like to punt a new row after each element having column "C" as discriminant (so if Column C is equal to Tail) with a "D" value equal to "Other". Then my desired output should be:

```
A    B      C      D
cat   Jack  Tail  short
cat   Jack  Tail  Medium
cat   Jack  Tail  Long
cat   Jack  Tail  Other
cat   Na    eye  blue
cat   Mik  Tail  short
cat   Mik  Tail  Medium
cat   Mik  Tail  Other
cat   Moon  Tail  short
cat   Moon  Tail  other
dog   Min   Tail  short
dog   Min   Tail  Other
dog   Spoon   Tail  short
dog   Spoon   Tail  medium
dog   Spoon   Tail  Long
dog   Spoon   Tail  Long
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `groupby`+`concat`:

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, g.iloc[-1:].assign(D='Other')]))
   #.reset_index(drop=True) # uncomment to have a fresh index
)
```

output:

```
     A      B     C       D
0  cat   Jack  Tail   short
1  cat   Jack  Tail  Medium
2  cat   Jack  Tail    Long
2  cat   Jack  Tail   Other
3  cat    Mik  Tail   short
4  cat    Mik  Tail  Medium
4  cat    Mik  Tail   Other
5  cat   Moon  Tail   short
5  cat   Moon  Tail   Other
6  dog    Min  Tail   short
6  dog    Min  Tail   Other
7  dog  Spoon  Tail   short
8  dog  Spoon  Tail  medium
9  dog  Spoon  Tail    Long
9  dog  Spoon  Tail   Other
```

Only add "Other" if the group only has "Tail" in C:

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False, group_keys=False, sort=False)
   .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g, g.iloc[-1:].assign(D='Other')])
                    if set(g['C']) == {'Tail'} else g
         )
)
```

output:

```
      A      B     C       D
0   cat   Jack  Tail   short
1   cat   Jack  Tail  Medium
2   cat   Jack  Tail    Long
2   cat   Jack  Tail   Other
3   cat     Na   eye    blue
4   cat    Mik  Tail   short
5   cat    Mik  Tail  Medium
5   cat    Mik  Tail   Other
6   cat   Moon  Tail   short
6   cat   Moon  Tail   Other
7   dog    Min  Tail   short
7   dog    Min  Tail   Other
8   dog  Spoon  Tail   short
9   dog  Spoon  Tail  medium
10  dog  Spoon  Tail    Long
10  dog  Spoon  Tail   Other
```

Comment: thank you. I forgot an important point in the original post question (now updated), columns C should be the discriminant to apply the formula. Then if C=='Tail' we can apply it. How should I change your reply according to the mentioned condition?

Comment: @user3043636 can you update your question to reflect this point? What should happen if there is a row with another value?

Comment: I updated the question, if there would be a row with another value I don't need to add the "Other".

Comment: @user3043636 I don't see the update, you mean anywhere in the group in C?

Comment: I have updated also the example now

Comment: @user3043636 see update, I hope you understand the general logic if you need to amend ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new dataframe with only the new rows and only when column `C` is `"Tail"`, then append, then sort:

```
df_other = df[["A", "B", "C"]].query("C == 'Tail'").drop_duplicates().assign(D="Other")

pd.concat([df, df_other]).sort_values(["A", "B"])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I forgot an important point, columns C should be the discriminant to apply the formula. Then if C=='Tail' we can apply it. How should I change your reply according to the mentioned condition?

Comment: Gotcha, see answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    idxmax2 = dd.query("C=='Tail'").index.max()
    dd.loc[idxmax2+1,"D"]="Other"
    return dd.ffill()

df1.groupby('B').apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out：

```
        A      B     C       D
0   cat   Jack  Tail   short
1   cat   Jack  Tail  Medium
2   cat   Jack  Tail    Long
3   cat   Jack  Tail   Other
4   cat    Mik  Tail   short
5   cat    Mik  Tail  Medium
6   cat    Mik  Tail   Other
7   dog    Min  Tail   short
8   dog    Min  Tail   Other
9   cat   Moon  Tail   short
10  cat   Moon  Tail   Other
11  cat     Na   eye    blue
12  cat     Na   eye   Other
13  dog  Spoon  Tail   short
14  dog  Spoon  Tail  medium
15  dog  Spoon  Tail    Long
16  dog  Spoon  Tail   Other
```